# Does Ixia Qcheck support IPv6?

Tags: performance, ipv6, testing

I'm trying to use Ixia Qcheck 3 on Windows 7. The QCheck documentation does not indicate whether IPv6 is supported. However it does say that addresses up to 64 characters are supported, so that would seem to represent IPv6.

The program works as expected with IPv4 addresses. When I enter IPv6 addresses for Endpoint 1 and Endpoint 2, I get error CHR0144 "the hostname is not found".  So it seems to think the IPv6 address (which are entered in the form of fe80::4221:00ff:fe00:0289) is a host name and not an address.

Has anyone used Qcheck with IPv6 addresses?

Answer (score 1):

Qcheck is an old tool which is not really maintained, and does not support much. It's just a free teaser for the more serious and costly IxChariot. IxChariot uses the same performance endpoints as Qcheck, and IPv6 is supported.

Disclaimer: My company is an IxChariot distributor (but probably not in your region...)

Comment: Eirik - I was unable to find any pricing for IxChariot on Ixia's web site. Usually that means "if you have to ask how much it is, you can't afford it". Can you provide a rough estimate of IxChariot cost?